# OpenCV Video with Tkinter and threading Crash

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a multithreaded program with Python, OpenCV, and Tkinter.
My program has some general point.

- Load Video from file
- Create 2 thread
- 1st thread to fetch frames from capture object and put it to python Queue
- 2nd thread to get the frames from Queue
- At last, if possible, start and stop the capture object

However, my script seems to behave weirdly. Sometimes it can finish playing video until the end, but sometimes it also crash at some point of the video. Here is what I've got so far.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Text
from Tkinter import PhotoImage
from ttk import Frame, Scrollbar, Button, Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv
import time
import Queue
import threading

def writeToLog(log, msg):
    numlines = log.index('end - 1 line').split('.')[0]
    if log.index('end-1c')!='1.0': log.insert('end', '\n')
    log.insert('end', msg)
    log.see('end')

def GetIplImageMode(img):
    orientation = 1 if img.origin == 0 else -1
    mode_list = {(1, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U)  : ("L", "L", 1),\
                 (3, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U)  : ("BGR", "RGB", 3),\
                 (1, cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F) : ("F", "F", 4)}
    key = (img.nChannels, img.depth)
    modes = mode_list[key]
    return [modes[0], modes[1], orientation]

def IplImage2PIL(img, mode):
    return Image.fromstring(mode[1], (img.width, img.height),\
                            img.tostring(), "raw", mode[0],\
                            img.width * img.channels,\
                            mode[2])

def ResizePILImage(pil, width = 260, height = 180):
    return pil.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

def PIL2TkImage(pil):
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil)

def setImageLabelFromIplImage(label, img_ipl):
    mode = GetIplImageMode(img_ipl)
    img_pil = IplImage2PIL(img_ipl, mode)
    img_resized = ResizePILImage(img_pil)
    img_tk = PIL2TkImage(img_resized)
    label.configure(image = img_tk)
    label.image = img_tk

def setImageLabelFromFile(label, szFileName):
    img_ipl = cv.LoadImage(szFileName)
    setImageLabelFromIplImage(label, img_ipl)

def mat_from_ipl(ipl):
    return cv.GetMat(ipl)

def ipl_from_mat(mat):
    ipl = cv.CreateImageHeader((mat.width, mat.height),\
                               cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, mat.channels)
    cv.SetData(ipl, mat.tostring())
    return ipl

class asdf(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.parent = parent
        self.variables()
        self.ui()
    def variables(self):
        self.ctr = 0
        self.fps = 0
        self.video = None
        self.image = None
        self.putProc = None
        self.getProc = None
        self.isRunning = False
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
    def ui(self):
        f1 = Frame(self)
        frm1 = Frame(f1)
        self.lbl1 = Label(frm1, image=None)
        setImageLabelFromFile(self.lbl1, '../image.bmp')
        self.txt1 = Text(frm1, width=30, height=8)
        sb1 = Scrollbar(frm1, orient='vertical', command=self.txt1.yview)
        self.txt1.configure(yscrollcommand = sb1.set)
        self.lbl1.pack()
        self.txt1.pack(side='left')
        sb1.pack(side='left', fill='y')
        frm1.pack(side='left')
        frm2 = Frame(f1)
        self.lbl2 = Label(frm2, image=None)
        setImageLabelFromFile(self.lbl2, '../image.bmp')
        self.txt2 = Text(frm2, width=30, height=8)
        sb2 = Scrollbar(frm2, orient='vertical', command=self.txt2.yview)
        self.txt2.configure(yscrollcommand = sb2.set)
        self.lbl2.pack()
        self.txt2.pack(side='left')
        sb2.pack(side='left', fill='y')
        frm2.pack(side='left')
        f1.pack()
        f2 = Frame(self)
        Button(f2, text='Run', command=self.run).pack(side='left')
        Button(f2, text='Stop', command=self.stop).pack(side='left')
        f2.pack()
    def put_to_queue(self):
        while self.isRunning:
            self.ctr = self.ctr + 1
            self.image = cv.QueryFrame(self.video)
            time.sleep(1 / self.fps)
            try:
                writeToLog(self.txt1, '\nPut to queue .. %d' % (self.ctr))
                temp1 = cv.CloneImage(self.image)
                setImageLabelFromIplImage(self.lbl1, temp1)
                temp2 = mat_from_ipl(temp1)
                self.queue.put([self.ctr, temp2])
            except:
                writeToLog(self.txt1, '\nReach end of video ..')
                break
    def get_from_queue(self):
        while self.isRunning:
            from_queue = self.queue.get()
            self.ctr_fr = from_queue[0]
            if self.ctr_fr == self.ctr: time.sleep(30 / self.fps)
            temp1 = ipl_from_mat(from_queue[1])
            setImageLabelFromIplImage(self.lbl2, temp1)
            writeToLog(self.txt2, '\nGet from queue .. %d' % (self.ctr_fr))
            time.sleep(1 / self.fps)
    def run(self):
        self.isRunning = True
        self.video = cv.CreateFileCapture('../video.avi')
        self.fps = cv.GetCaptureProperty(self.video, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
        writeToLog(self.txt1, '\nStart put_queue ..')
        self.putProc = threading.Thread(target=self.put_to_queue)
        self.putProc.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        writeToLog(self.txt2, '\nStart get_queue ..')
        self.getProc = threading.Thread(target=self.get_from_queue)
        self.getProc.start()
    def stop(self):
        self.isRunning = False
        if self.putProc.isAlive():
            self.putProc._Thread__stop()
            writeToLog(self.txt1, '\nputProc still alive, stopping ..')
            self.putProc = None
        if self.getProc.isAlive():
            self.getProc._Thread__stop()
            writeToLog(self.txt2, '\ngetProc still alive, stopping ..')
            self.getProc = None
        self.ctr_fr = 0
        self.ctr = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    c = asdf(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Any ideas will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try to make a minimal example please, and what is question? you say that you can get code to work? im confused hehe.

Comment: @W1ll1amvl: Thanks for reply. I'm sorry if my question was not clear. The problem is my code sometimes works nice, but sometimes it fails and I have no idea for what causing my code to fail. I posted my whole code so anyone can try and test my code. Thanks

Comment: All good, interesting that it sometimes works and sometimes not...

Comment: @W1ll1amvl: So, you have tried my code and experienced the same problem? May be what causing my code to fail is something about dealing with opencv mat and python queue correctly and for starting and stopping the video, it must be something about releasing the opencv capture object. But I'm still welcoming other ideas and suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Hi, no I havent tried the code out it won't work as I don't have PIL etc. Maybe try running code on a different computer and see if that works better? otherwise I don't have too many ideas.